# For loop for printing to file loads forever and file blank even though closed?

Tags: java, for-loop, printwriter

I am trying to write code that simulated the Monte-Carlo method for more than 1000 trials by choosing a random number out of 10 and until the number is 10 then a counter for (number of squirrels observed) will be increased each time until the random number is 10; this counter will then be printed to a file. However this is done with a For loop with nested loops within in but the program seems to load forever once at this For loop and the file remains blank even though the close() is used.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class AnimalPopulation
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
    //declare and initialize variables
    Random randsquirrel = new Random();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new File ("squirreldata.txt"));

    // User input
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Fox Squirrel Simulator");
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("How many trials should be simulated?");
    System.out.println("Enter a value greater than 1000:");
    int trialcounter = in.nextInt();

    // Input does not match requirements
    while (trialcounter <= 1000)
    {
        System.out.print("\n\n  Please try again. Enter a number greater than 1000.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("How many trials should be simulated?");
        System.out.println("Enter a value greater than 1000:");
        trialcounter = in.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("\nsimulating trials now... one moment please ...");

    // Experiment with ratio of 1/10 fox squirrels 
    int randomsquirrel = 0;
    int totalsquirrels = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= trialcounter; i++)
    {
        randomsquirrel = randsquirrel.nextInt(10)+1;
            while (randomsquirrel != 10)
            {

                totalsquirrels++;
            }
                if (randomsquirrel == 10);
                {
                    totalsquirrels++;
                }
        outFile.println(totalsquirrels);
    }
    outFile.close();

    // Read file and print result
    File readfile = new File ("squirreldata.txt");
    Scanner readFile2 = new Scanner(readfile);
    Double trialtotalsquirrels = 0.0;
    while(readFile2.hasNextLine())
    {
        String token = readFile2.nextLine();
        int totalsquirrels2 = Integer.parseInt(token);
        trialtotalsquirrels += totalsquirrels2;
    }
    readFile2.close();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The results!");
    System.out.println("The average number of squirrels observed until\n spotting a Fox Squirrel at the city part is: " + trialtotalsquirrels/trialcounter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell me what's wrong here?

```
    randomsquirrel = randsquirrel.nextInt()+1;
    while (randomsquirrel != 10)
    {
        totalsquirrels++;
    }
```

While loops has 3 parts the while key word, the (condition), and the {lines to run}

```
while (condition) {
    //lines to run.
}
```

First the condition is checked if it is turn it will perform all the lines to run.
After all the lines are done it checks the condition again.  If the condition is still true it will run all the lines again.  It will keep on running the lines **forever** until the condition becomes false or hits a break.

Comment: To clarify, I made an error in the original post: it should be randomsquirrel = randsquirrel.nextInt(10)+1; not sure why the 10 was deleted from the nextInt() when I was pasting it.

Comment: even with that change your code would still not work.  Do you know how a while loop works?  I don't mind explaining if you don't know.

Comment: i am currently learning it in my class right now but it doesn't work so i guess i don't actually understand how it works haha. i would greatly appreciate it if you could explain it to me and why this won't work

Comment: I edited my answer.  With that clue do you know why your code is failing?

Answer (score 0):

You use incorrect while because you will never change value in while loop and this cause a infinite loop. The correct way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    SecureRandom randsquirrel = new SecureRandom(); // it is better
    // rest of your code
    int randomsquirrel = 0;
    int totalsquirrels = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= trialcounter; i++)
    {
        randomsquirrel = randsquirrel.nextInt(10)+1;
        while (randomsquirrel != 10)
        {                               
            randomsquirrel = randsquirrel.nextInt(10) + 1:
            totalsquirrels++;
            if (randomsquirrel == 10);
                break;
        }                      
    }
    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: To clarify, I made an error in the original post: it should be randomsquirrel = randsquirrel.nextInt(10)+1;  not sure why the 10 was deleted from the nextInt() when I was pasting it.

Comment: I want to correct it but if I use `nextInt(10)` it only make 0 until 9 but `nextInt()` will create negitive numbers as far as I know. I think you do this on purpose.